# Visual Studio NatvisFile add leading zeros to DisplayString

Tags: visual-studio, visualizer, debuggervisualizer, natvis

I want to adjust my Visualizer in Visual Studio 2017 via the Nativis file.
There is an own class `date`, which should be displayed more nicely in the debugger.

```
<Type Name = "date">
        <DisplayString>"{1900 + ts.tm_year}-{1 + ts.tm_mon}-{ts.tm_mday}T{ts.tm_hour}:{ts.tm_min}:{ts.tm_sec}"</DisplayString>
</Type>
```

my current code shows something like this for a date in the debugger:

```
2018-1-1T0:0:0
```

However, I would like to have leading zeros. So like this:

```
2018-01-01T00:00:00
```

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: I don't think so. I added https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/389777/add-ability-to-specify-c-style-formats-to-format-s.html which is a more general mechanism which could solve your issue

Comment: Actually maybe there is a work around using Conditions. For a struct with a year, month, day you can do

Comment: `<Type Name="Date"><DisplayString Condition="month&lt;10 &amp;&amp; day&lt;10">{year}0{month}0{day}</DisplayString><DisplayString Condition="month&lt;10">{year}0{(int)month}{day}</DisplayString><DisplayString Condition="day&lt;10">{year}{month}0{day}</DisplayString><DisplayString>{year}{month}{day}</DisplayString></Type>`  Sorry but stackoverflow seems to reformat stuff